# rvm doesn't install in centos without root privileges

Tags: centos, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

I trying to install RVM using deployer user that doesn't had root privileges ant I getting this error:

```
bash: line 439: ./scripts/install: Permission denied
```

Any help? Thank you!

Comment: Be root? What do you think we're going to tell you -- Installing `rvm` pretty much requires administrative (root) privileges.

Comment: In RVM site: "Single-User installations (recommended) - For an isolated install within a user's $HOME, not for root." https://rvm.io/rvm/install/

Comment: `Multi-User installations - For server administrators `<- ; If you're talking about installing it for your personal use it's really more a question for [unix.se] than Server Fault. Your question is also poorly asked (you're just throwing an error message at us - you don't tell us what command you ran to get it, or what you've looked at to try to debug it on your own), hence "Not A Real Question" instead of off-topic. If you disagree with the close please open a discussion on http://meta.serverfault.com/

Comment: You're absolutely right!

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to do a non-multiuser install without root privileges. Are you starting with this command?

```
 curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

If so and that's what's failing, can you run the command again with the debug info enabled

```
 curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s -- --trace
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have root you can't do it. There is no way of bypassing the security mechanism. Linux/Unix don't allow a non privileged user to do a task which requires elevated privileges. 
In short unless you can get root.

Comment: https://rvm.io/rvm/install/: "Single-User installations (recommended) - For an isolated install within a user's $HOME, not for root."

Comment: Yes, your observation about unix security applies in general, but not to the question.  RVM runs within the non-root user's context.  The OP is initiating the installation incorrectly somehow.